# How to get only 2 values after the decimal point in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an value 938.2348

I want in decimal like 938.23 instead of full value.

How I can achieve this via XSLT 1.0?

Comment: `floor(938.2348 * 100) div 100` (or `round` instead of `floor` if you want to round up for 0.5 or higher).

Comment: I don't want to round up. I need the exact two digit after the point(.)

Comment: Then use the variant with `floor`.

Comment: Note that "the variant with `floor`" assumes the input is not negative.